# When NSDocument Asynchronous Saving is enabled, is there any point in calling -unblockUserInteraction in a simple -dataOfType:error:?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I have a straight-forward, Mac OS X, Cocoa, Document-based application which uses the new 10.7 Autosave, Versions and Asychronous Saving APIs. I am fully using the `NSDocument` APIs to get all of Apple's Document-based application features for free.

In order to support the new Lion Autosave/Versions/AsyncSaving, I have overridden the following methods in my `NSDocument` subclass like so:

```
@implementation MyDocument 
...
+ (BOOL)autosavesInPlace { return YES; }

- (BOOL)canAsynchronouslyWriteToURL:(NSURL *)URL ofType:(NSString *)type forSaveOperation:(NSSaveOperationType)op {
    return YES;
}
```

I have also overridden `-dataOfType:error:` to help implement saving the document's data to disk:

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outErr {
    NSData *data = nil;

    if ([typeName isEqualToString:MY_SUPPORTED_TYPE_NAME]) {
        data = makeSnapshotCopyOfMyDocumentData(); // assume return value is autoreleased
    } else if (outErr) {
        *outErr = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:unimpErr userInfo:nil];
    }

    // not sure this is doing much good, since i take no action after this.
    [self unblockUserInteraction];

    return data;
}
...
@end
```

See how I'm calling `-unblockUserInteraction` at the end there?

When supporting the new 10.7 AsyncSaving feature, Apple advises calling `-unblockUserInteraction` as early as possible (after making a snapshot copy of your document's data) in your `-dataOfType:error:` implementation. But Apple's example showed them doing much more work after calling `-unblockUserInteraction`.

However, considering I take no other action after this, I'm wondering if there's any point in calling `-unblockUserInteraction` there at all.

So my questions:

1. Considering I take no other action after it, is my call to `-unblockUserInteraction` doing any good?
2. Do the Apple Frameworks just call `-unblockUserInteraction` immediately after `-dataOfType:error:` returns anyway? Should I just leave it to them?

Answer (score 4):

I just noticed a subtle wording difference between the [NSDocument documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDocument/unblockUserInteraction) and the comment in NSDocument.h:

Docs:

> If saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler: is writing on
>   a non-main thread because
>   canAsynchronouslyWriteToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation: has returned YES,
>   but it is still blocking the main thread, this method unblocks the
>   main thread. **Otherwise, it does nothing.**

Header:

> If -saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler: is writing on
>   a non-main thread because
>   -canAsynchronouslyWriteToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation: has returned YES, but is still blocking the main thread, unblock the main thread.
>   **Otherwise, do nothing.**

I assume the Header is more up to date.

I am working on an application that calls `unblockUserInteraction` after the last line that has to run on the main thread. (At least that's the way I understood it)
I think our code fits the scenario that Apple had in mind when designing the async saving part of NSDocument:

in `fileWrapperOfType:` we ...

- create a QL preview for our file wrapper (that has to run on the
  main thread) ...
- `unblockUserInteraction` ...
- ... "long" running file saving task (involving compression)